# Browsers supporting event processing in dojox.gfx Surface

Tags: events, dojo, surface, gfx

Is events processing in dojox.gfx Surface supported by browsers other than Firefox 3?

Say, i have a variable named surface that is an instance of a gfx surface, i then listen to click events on it using

`surface.connect("onclick",null,function(e){
      console.debug("clicked on the surface");
});`

It works in Firefox 3, but it doesn't in IE8, Goggle Chrome 3, adn Safari 4. Can I do anything about it, or is it not supported by those 3 browsers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should work everywhere. But a surface is a container, not an object. Try to catch clicks on shapes. If you still want to use a container, try to catch clicks on a DOM node that is used to define your surface.